# python pandas histogram plot including NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

I wanted to draw a histogram of some data. sorry that I could not attach a sample histogram as I don't have enough reputation. Hope that my description of the problem I am facing will be understood by you.  I am using python pandas and I realize that any NaN value is treated as a 0 by pandas. Is there any method that I can use to include the count of Nan value in the histogram? What I mean is that the x-axis should have the NaN value as well. Please help... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the same thing. I ended up with the following solution:

```
figure = plt.figure(figsize=(6,9), dpi=100);    
graph = figure.add_subplot(111);

freq = pandas.value_counts(data)
bins = freq.index
x=graph.bar(bins, freq.values) #gives the graph without NaN

graphmissing = figure.add_subplot(111)
y = graphmissing.bar([0], freq[numpy.NaN]) #gives a bar for the number of missing values at x=0

figure.show()
```

This gave me a histogram with a column at 0 showing the number of missing values in the data.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [Sreeram TP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7896849/sreeram-tp), it is possible to use the argument dropna=False in the function value_counts to include the counts of NaNs.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'feature1': [1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, np.NaN],
                   'feature2': [4, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 3, np.NaN, np.NaN]})

# Calculates the histogram for feature1
counts = df['feature1'].value_counts(dropna=False)

counts.plot.bar(title='feat1', grid=True)
```

I can not insert images. So, here is the result:
[image plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdXtl.png)

Comment: You can make use of `dropna` argument in `value_counts()` like `value_counts(dropna=False)` to get the count of nan directly

Answer (score 1):

Did you try replacing NaN with some other unique value and then plot the histogram?

```
x= some unique value

plt.hist(df.replace(np.nan, x)
```

Comment: This is the simplest possible solution. I favour this over the accepted answer. The following does the job with `numpy` imported as `np`. `df.column_name.replace(np.nan, 'any_text_or_number').value_counts().plot(kind='bar')`

Comment: However after due consideration, this method allows less flexibility in case of subplots.

Answer (score 0):

By using `.iloc[::-1]` on the output of `value_counts()`, you can reverse its order.

The code would look like this:

```py
df["column"].value_counts().iloc[::-1]
```

Comment: This is true, but we no longer get a graphical histogram - rather a listing of values.